# porting an app built using Tornado framework to Django framework

Tags: angularjs, django, tornado, single-page-application, web-development-server

I have an app that was developed using Tornado framework and Angularjs.
the app is basically a game with two type of users a moderator and players. the moderator and players exchange data in "real time" and a graph is updated based on their input.

I am a decent coder but new to web development and this is just an in case question. Since the app has some issues, and since I will have to learn a framework anyway, I would rather learn Django. I was wondering if there is a resource out there that makes the conversion easier?

What I am looking for is advice on how to tackle this in a way where I don't have to go through the documentation of both frameworks before I can do anything useful.

Ideally, I'd like to incrementally learn more about both frameworks as I make meaningful edits to the app.

Comment: Tornado is a much much easier than a Django, the hardest thing to understand is concepts of async and event-driven programming. After that Tornado is pretty easy as it consists of only a few components and don't force specific architecture. Django have many built-in components and force certain style of building a project, so you really need to learn that first. Finally, if your project relies mostly on web-sockets, Tornado is a better choice as even Django can handle web-sockets with Django-Channels, it will require more resources for the same amount of connections, than a Tornado would.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see you need to get familiar with two things. [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)` which is a great tool, with a really good documentation. Basically it helps you to communicate with you application by REST API. And of course Django. 
They also have a tutorial made for starting your way with Django. Which basically have everything needed to start. If you have an experience with Tornado, you will have no problem to work with Django. Here is a [link to tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/).

Comment: I am a little greedy, would you advise that I take a backbone Django/Rest/Angular project from GitHub and then add code snippets to it with a few edits. or Will that just complicate my life and I should go through the documentation?

Comment: I`d recommend using already written code only for checkup, how people are doing things. The fastest way to learn is to write from scratch. Very simple application can be made within an hour or two, for example a blog page.